# Can we say "I am meeting a doctor for my leg tomorrow"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The meaning of "see" and "meet" in the dictionary seem alike.

[to see](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/see) [transitive] to have an arranged meeting with someone

[to meet](https://%20%5Bintransitive,%20transitive%5D%20to%20go%20to%20a%20place%20where%20someone%20will%20be%20at%20a%20particular%20time,%20according%20to%20an%20arrangement,%20so%20that%20you%20can%20talk%20or%20do%20something%20together) [intransitive, transitive] to go to a place where someone will be at a particular time, according to an arrangement, so that you can talk or do something together

I think we can say:

-"*I am seeing a doctor about my leg tomorrow*"

-"*I am seeing a client for our contract tomorrow*"

-"*I am meeting a client for our contract tomorrow*".

But I am not sure if we say "*I am meeting a doctor for my leg tomorrow*"

Can we say "*I am meeting a doctor for my leg tomorrow*"?

Comment: 'Meeting a doctor' as a patient would sound odd to a native speaker. We see a doctor about something medical.

Comment: "Meet" involves more of a 2-way exchange; two doctors might meet to discuss someone else's leg, but if you're going for medical advice/treatment, "see" is the usual verb in casual speech (or just "going to a doctor"). You might "consult" a doctor if you were writing something very formal and wanted to pretend you were learned.

Comment: @StuartF: Your comment covers pretty much everything on this perfectly valid question, so I think you should post it up as an answer.

Comment: I'm unsure why you think that the three example sentences are correct but have questions about the other sentence. Why do you think that there's a difference?

Answer (score 1):

To "see" a doctor/client/etc. is an idiomatic expression which means to visit with that person *about the normal things you'd meet with them for*. In the case of a doctor, it means about a medical problem. In the case of a client, it means to discuss business. In the case of an insurance adjuster, for instance, it would probably be about an insurance claim.

To "meet" a doctor/client/etc. has no idiomatic meaning that extends beyond the normal dictionary meaning of "meet". You may meet with your client and discuss business, or you may just go for a beer.

Further, people tend to only have one doctor, so if you say you're going to "meet a doctor", it sounds like some random person who happens to be a doctor, so probably not for medical reasons. If you say, "meet **my** doctor", it means your own doctor, so probably for medical reasons.